# Priority on css classes

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a span with 2 classes, like this `<span class="tag invalid_tag">abc</span>`. I add the second class through jQuery correctly and i need the properties from the second class to override the first, without actually removing it. For instance, the properties are the font color and background-color. Usually the tag is green but when i add the class "invalid_tag" it should turn red but it doesn't because the first class has the priority. I would like to know how to change this priority, or if i can achieve this in a different way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The priority of CSS declarations relies on their order in the CSS (later declarations override earlier ones) and their specificity (more specific declarations override less-specific ones). (It has nothing to do with the order you specify the class names in the attribute.) More in **[Section 6](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/cascade.html)** the specification.

Here's an example of order. This CSS

```
.foo {
    color: red;
}
.bar {
    color: blue;
}
```

with this HTML

```
<p class="foo bar">Hi there</p>
<p class="bar foo">Hi again</p>
```

...results in two blue paragraphs, because the second declaration takes precedence over the first. ([Live example](http://jsbin.com/okevit)) That happens because both declarations have the same specificity.

Here's a demonstration of specificity:

This CSS

```
p.foo {
    color: red;
}
.bar {
    color: blue;
}
```

...with the same HTML results in two *red* paragraphs, because the selector `p.foo` is more specific than the selector `.bar`, so it takes precedence even though it's earlier in the CSS. ([Live example](http://jsbin.com/okevit/2))

Comment: Furthermore, you could achieve this effect with a more specific rule for bar. http://jsfiddle.net/PmPhf/1/ This way the rule can be anywhere and will still override. Check out the fantastic http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/images/specificitywars-05v2.jpg

Comment: @Erik: I addressed specificity, I'm not sure what point you're making...?

Comment: Yes, yes. Yours was a great answer. I just wanted to push the limits of specificity and include the chart that I've found to be most useful regarding it. Cheers!